# Jedis - high performing servlet - settings

Tags: java, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jedis, amazon-elasticache

We are running a servlet on Elastic Beanstalk where we connect to ElastiCache and it's running fairly well but now we are getting high CPU loads (50%) in peak periods and are looking into optimizing it.

At the moment we are using Jedis like this:

```
try (Jedis jedis = new Jedis(Global.CLUSTER_ENDPOINT, 6379, 10000);) {              
    jedis.hset(f.dayOfFile, "content", f.xmlFile);
}
```

One issue we have is that the number of active connections suddenly rose to 8400 and is not going down. Doesn't seem to affect anything but still wonder how it went that high and if that affects performance.

So my question is:

1. Should we use another library like lettuce (https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) which seems better maintained?
2. Or should we use connection pooling? We have millions of requests each day so a bit afraid to switch over to connection pooling if that introduces other issues like max connections in the pool?
3. Or is there anything else we should tweak?

Comment: instead of being afraid of it, you could try #2 [in some test environemnt]. Having an unbound (non poopled) connection count seems like a bad idea to me. Or do you an unbound amount of `new Thread()`s too?

Comment: @zapl A bit difficult simulating 3 million users to make sure it doesn't fail in the peak periods. But if that is the recommended way to set it up I will change it and look at some scale test solution to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it is difficult. But having a way to verify changes beforehand (and a way for emergency roll back) is required if you don't want to get stuck in the long run with lots of code that nobody wants to touch again. Beanstalk has to my knowledge unfortunately no features like A/B testing of versions like http://www.programmableweb.com/news/google-app-engine-now-supports-ab-testing/2012/02/29 but you should be able to do something similar at load balancer level. There are also several load testing services and frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jedis is a small and nice library if you want to do "just" some Redis. It's blazing fast because it does just its job. Jedis' scalability is limited by threads/connections and the connections are not thread-safe. You can use connection pooling, and I strongly believe, this would help to address your issue.

The code from above connects/disconnects from/to Redis every time it is called. Pooling could help. jedis uses commons-pool2 that is a quite good implementation for connection pooling but slower in comparison to other frameworks.

You could implement connection pooling by yourself, to improve on the high connection count issue.

You asked about lettuce: With lettuce, you need only one connection, because lettuce connections are thread-safe (as long you do not use blocking operations [`BLPOP`] or transactions [`EXEC`/`DISPATCH`]). Lettuce is slightly slower than jedis but provides:

- Thread-safety
- Auto-reconnect and command buffering when the connection is down
- An asynchronous API

lettuce does not provide read-from-slaves (yet) when using Redis Standalone (or Redis Master/Slave). There is also no failover/service discovery for ElastiCache (failover is supported only with Redis Sentinel).

A drawback might be the command pattern of lettuce because lettuce creates a command for every command that you issue. Depending on the usage, commands can eat up a significant part of your memory. This, however, depends on your point of view.

HTH, Mark

Comment: Yes, Jedis works very good and performant with connection pooling. Easy and nice, it _"just works"_.
Also Jedis works perfectly with Sentinel, doing re-connects to slaves. No problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redisson](https://redisson.org) it has support of AWS Elasticache service and provides connection pool and most convenient Java api to Redis.